# Perform an action at a certain time

Tags: c#, timer

I'm writing a piece of software in C# that allows a user to select times for a certain action to happen. Let's say this is something as simple as displaying a message box at certain times.

These times can be saved (in a DB/config file). If the application is running at any of the times specified then I want the action to be performed.

My first idea on how to achieve this would be to have some sort of polling functionality that checks every second to see if there are timers set for this second. This idea seems a little naive.

My second idea is to load the collection of timers into memory on launch, then instantiating background threads with delays calculated based on the time until the timer should fire.

Is there a best-practice strategy for implementing this?

Comment: I would move this to the software engineering StackOverflow

Comment: `Hangfire` if it is Server action to execute background task,
`SignalR` if that action to be performed is on web client eg, Notification

Comment: If on windows maybe TaskScheduler?

Comment: Quartz https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this a strategy, but you could just have one timer for the first action, then after performing the action set the timer for the next action.

And make sure that you also "reset" the timer whenever you add or change the schedule.